# I installed the flutter search field 0.6.2 package and I am getting an error while adding the item

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have installed a package to add a dropdownfield to my project, but I want the field to look like in [this video](https://youtu.be/CwTEdazQUlg). I am getting the below error.

```
//DropdownSearch
                      Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Select a country',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: SearchField(
                                suggestions: [
                                  'Afghanistan',
                                  'Turkey',
                                  'Germany',
                                  'France',
                                  'Italy',
                                  'Spain',
                                  'United Kingdom',
                                  'United States',
                                  'Canada',
                                  'Australia',
                                  'New Zealand',
                                  'India',
                                  'Indonesia',
                                  'Bangladesh',
                                  'Sri Lanka',
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Error code:

[image: Error code (image1)]

Error code:

[image: Error Code (image2)]

Error message:

```
    The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<SearchFieldListItem<dynamic>>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
Couldn't infer type parameter 'E'.
```

--

```
Tried to infer 'String' for 'E' which doesn't work:
  Return type declared as 'List<E>'
              used where  'List<SearchFieldListItem<_>>' is required.
The type 'String' was inferred from:
  Parameter 'element' declared as     'E'
                      but argument is 'String'.

Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you are passing a List of string into a List that accepts SearchFieldListItem object with a type of dynamic(any type). Try to add the items in your list into and List with the given object.

Comment: Can you be more specific and elaborate how the code should look like.